# Interceptor does not catch EJBAccessException

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly

I'm using Wildfly 12 (EE 8).

I'm trying to catch EJBAccessException to rethrow it as my own exception type via my Interceptor but to no avail. The code in my Interceptor does not get called at all when it is thrown. It does work and does catch other exceptions though, so I'm not sure what's wrong. Does the EJB somehow not recognise my Interceptor regarding this "internal" issue, or does it maybe get called only after the Wildfly's own AuthorizationInterceptor is called?

My ejb-jar.xml:

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor>
        <interceptor-class>myExceptionInterceptor</interceptor-class>
    </interceptor>
</interceptors>
<assembly-descriptor>
    <interceptor-binding>
        <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
        <interceptor-class>myExceptionInterceptor</interceptor-class>
    </interceptor-binding>
</assembly-descriptor>
```

My beans.xml is empty, I also tried putting the Interceptor declaration there but with no effect.

My interceptor:

```
@Throws
@Interceptor
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION) // Tried playing with this too
public class myExceptionInterceptor implements Serializable {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object check(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {
    try {
        return invocationContext.proceed();
    }
    catch (javax.ejb.EJBAccessException e) {
        //rethrow as own exception
    }
```

Part of my standalone.xml regarding EJB security:

```
<default-security-domain value="jaspitest"/>
<default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
```

My Interceptor binding:

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target( {ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE} )
public @interface Throws {}
```

An example bean I'm calling it on:

```
@Stateless
public class UserService extends Service<User> {
   @RolesAllowed(Role.ADMIN)
   public void delete() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work because your interceptor is required to have access to the same [javax.ejb.EJBContext](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html) object that its associated business methods have. See Table 2 in §4.7.2 of the EJB Specification (3.2).

Therefore, the security checks are applied *before* your interceptor is invoked.

The only way around this would be to wrap your service in an unsecured facade and apply your interceptors to that.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something like that. I think I'll just implement my own RolesAllowed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to solve this with a container interceptor. 
[Container interceptors](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Container+interceptors)
- put the next xml into a jboss-ejb3.xml file:

```
<jboss xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:jee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:ci ="urn:container-interceptors:1.0">

<jee:assembly-descriptor>
    <ci:container-interceptors>
        <jee:interceptor-binding>
            <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
            <interceptor-class>YOUR FULLY QUALIFIED INTERCEPTOR CLASS GOES HERE</interceptor-class>
        </jee:interceptor-binding>            
    </ci:container-interceptors>
</jee:assembly-descriptor></jboss>
```

- copy the jboss-ejb3.xml into your deployment resources/META-INF.
- create the interceptor as simple as in the example in the linked WildFly documentation

You can catch the EJBAccessException after you call invocationContext.proceed().